# Implementing an IP Gateway (in Java?)

Tags: java, routes, ip

I'd like to write a program to simulate various network conditions (e.g. latency, packet loss).  The most straight-forward presentation of that program would be for it to be configured as an IP gateway - clients send traffic to it either as a default gateway, or downstream routers have it set up as a next-hop for routing purposes.

How can I write a program to receive and process that traffic?

What tools and libraries are available to allow this? e.g. Can this be done through iptables on linux?
(I'd prefer to implement it in Java if possible).

One work around could be to implement such a program as a proxy (e.g. HTTP + SOCKS) and configure a router to send all traffic to the proxy transparently. Another could be to open a raw socket and manually process all the traffic, but this might effectively mean re-implementing a network stack.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad so the answer will be just as broad. I hope it helps you find some preliminary directions to research.

First, try to avoid writing anything at all. There are existing solutions for this task (hint: search for "WAN Emulator").

If what you find isn't good enough, my next step would be to script something using [tc](http://How%20can%20I%20write%20a%20program%20to%20receive%20and%20process%20that%20traffic?) and [netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem). Linux has very good support for both routing and bridging. Using tc+netem you could add delay, loss, jitter and and just about anything else on top. If needed, create a higher level utility, possibly in Java to configure tc and provide a nicer UI.

A third option would be to actually write something. This is where things get tricky, especially if you want to do it in java. To perform bridging or routing, you'd need to get the frames to user space ([iptables+nfqueue](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/) could help here), then handle them according to your own logic, and finally write them out [using a raw socket](https://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/). That's quite a lot of work.

Implementing an HTTP proxy would be easier since you don't need to work at the level of individual packets. You can avoid the low level stuff (iptables/nfqueue/raw sockets) and just use plain and simple sockets, or even whole HTTP proxy implementations in Java like [this one from Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/proxy-servlet.html).

If you need further details about some of this stuff, you might want to open a second, more focused question after doing some reading.